# Make randomised sprites in a specific co-ordinate do something

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I was wondering if anyone could help me with my program,
I have randomised my sprites into a specific set of co-ordinates. 
I want one of the sprites that is at that specific co-ordinate, to be able to make them do something when they are at this random co-ordinate. The problem i am having is that i have to make a long list of if statements saying if this sprite is here do this if another sprite is here do the exact same thing.

if (red1.position.y>=0 && red1.position.y<=63) {
  id r1animation = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.2 position:ccp(red1.position.x,33)];
  [red1 runAction:r1animation];
 }
 if (red2.position.y>=0 && red2.position.y<=63) {
  id r2animation = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.2 position:ccp(red2.position.x,33)];
  [red2 runAction:r2animation];
 }
i want to be able to say if any of the sprites are at that exact co-ordinate then move them to a point, in a short amount of code as possible. so basically grouping the sprites or something i'm not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> i want to be able to say if any of the sprites are at that exact co-ordinate then move them to a point

Firstly, specify the 'hotspot' programatically:

```
CGPoint hotspot = ccp(32,32); // convenience macro, 
                              //creates a CGPoint with x = 32, y = 32
```

You should store a reference to all your sprites in an array when you create them (you can use cocos2d's 'tagging' also, but I usually like to use an array for simplicity)

```
-(void)init {
 //.. misc
 // creating sprite returns a reference so keep it in an array
 CCSprite* curSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: //...etc]
 [self.spriteArray addObject: curSprite];
 // add all sprite references to your array
}
```

Now you can iterate over this array to see if any of the sprite's frames overlap the hotspot:

```
-(BOOL) checkAllSpritesForCollision
{
  for (CCSprite *sp in self.spriteArray)
  {
    CGRect spriteRect = sp.frame;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(spriteRect,hotspot))
    {
       // run your action on sp...
    }
  }

  // you might like to return YES if a collision happened?
}
```

This is a brute force method of checking whether every sprites frame contains a given point. There are many ways to skin this cat of course, but hopefully this will set you on a better path.

Comment: thanks for the example, when i try compiling the code i get 2 errors, saying request for member 'spriteArray','frame' in something not a structure or union.The code is in cctouchmoved.
 CGPoint T1 = ccp(33,33);
 CGRect r1;
 r1 = CGRectMake(0,0,480,66);
 for (CCSprite *sp in self.spriteArray) {
  CGRect spriteRect = sp.frame;
  if (CGRectContainsPoint(r1, touchLocation)) {
   if (CGRectContainsPoint(spriteRect, T1)) {
    prevLocation.y= touchLocation.y;
    CGPoint diffx = ccpSub(touchLocation, prevLocation);
    CGPoint r1pos = [red1 position];
    [red1 setPosition:ccpAdd(diffx, r1pos)];}}}

Comment: i've now got an array of sprite positions and i have got another array of rects. i want to be able to say if the array of sprites is in any of the array of rects do this

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to calculate the distance:

```
    float pointX = thePoint.position.x;
float pointY = thePoint.position.y;

float pointDeltax = sprite.position.x-pointX;
float pointDeltay = sprite.position.y-pointY;
float pointDist = sqrt(pointDeltax*pointDeltax+pointDeltay*pointDeltay);
```

But maybe davbryns solution suits your purpose better.